# How to mount exFAT/FAT partitions as user without all files having the executable bit set in permissions?

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, udev, udisks

Ubuntu 23.04 here, but should apply to almost every version.

I want to mount external drives via the user mount mechanisms in the system (is `udev` involved?), often over SSH with `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdX`.

VFAT/exFAT drives show up with permissions 755, which is annoying since I don't want the executable bit set when I copy files. How can I force `udisksctl` (or is it `udev` under the hood?) to mount these drives with 644 permissions on all files?

My attempts with the `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` file were not successful.

Setting of `exfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,noexec` didn't do the trick.

I restarted with `sudo systemctl restart udisks2.service` to make sure the changes were loaded.

Comment: Udev is involved in making the block device available and then It's udisks2 that mounts filesystems and `udisksctl` is a command to manage it ... Those filesystems, however, don't support Unix/Linux permissions anyway.

Comment: But they get mounted with permissions, and these defaults must be set somewhere. And the permissions stay when I copy to the internal drive.
Yes, it's `udisks2`, but I was working under the assumption that `udisks2` might call `udev` for the ground work.

Comment: "But they get mounted with permissions." ... Actually AFAIK no ... The permissions you see are for the mount point ... There might be a way to mask that in e.g. `/etc/fstab` so you might want to search for that.

Comment: `noexec` blocks execution of files irrespective of the mode, what you want are `fmask`/`dmask`/`umask`

Comment: Masking in `/etc/fstab` is  not useful since these are often changing removable disks which cannot be put in `/etc/fstab`. And the mount point `/media/user` is also generated on the fly by the system and has certain attributes set, where could I change these then? By the way, the attributes are `drwxr-x---+`, so not the same as an `a=x` attribute set after mounting VFAT/exFAT systems.

Comment: @muru: Good find, but a `exfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,fmask=0644` line in `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` and restart of service still gives the same result: all files have attribute `a=x`.

Comment: It's a mask, not the desired mode. Try something like `0133`

Comment: The x-bit usually is set for showing one of the attributes of a FAT file (archive, hidden or read-only) which are not known by Posix.